# Is there a numeric road identifier in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm looking for a way to identify roads or streets on google maps.
I don't need the road name, just an identifier for a road. And I don't really care if GPS coordinate is really on the road as long as the results are consistent.

I need this in order to determine if two GPS coordinates are on the same road.
Now I know I can compare the road name between the two coordinates using geocoder but In some cases the road name is null, and I actually don't care about the name itself.

Is there any road ID that I can get using a geocoder ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by the 'same road'?

A road can have many different names and designations at the same time and over its length.

Consider Route 66 do you want to be considered to be on the same road if you are on the same road if your two locations are on route 66 near Los Angeles and Chicago or is it a series of different roads as wends its way through the cities en-route?

Should a road have a different id if has an arbitrary name change as it goes round a bend or crosses from one town to the next?

Comment: As long as it is route 66 than yes. I want it to be route 66 all way long.

Comment: Then I think you are going to be out of luck.  How is Google going to know that you are interested in a long distance road and not in High street vs Church street as the road passes through a small town enroute.